# Usage of some vs. some of

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I would like to ask if any specific rules apply to the usage of *some* and *some of* phrases and especially in which cases either of them is not suitable for a sentence.

I understand that e.g. a phrase like *some of my friends* is grammatically correct, but what makes me hesitate is the following sentence from the field of physics:

> Some of relevant ideas were mentioned many years ago.

Can the *of* preposition be used in this case, or is the sentence incorrect?

(As a side note, I think that the word *mentioned* is not chosen very well and should be replaced by a more suitable verb or a construction saying that there have been scientists who stated important theorems such as the divisibility of atoms.)

Comment: The ***of*** issue would be better addressed on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (basically, it's completely unacceptable in the cited context). Better alternatives to ***mentioned*** include ***raised, put forward, advanced, discussed***, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Using the word 'the' between 'of' and 'relevant' could help to make more sense or remove the word 'of' altogether.